# Runtime.exec() fail to execute in Windows Server until I login

Tags: java, exec

The code is simple:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\path\\to\\exefile");
```

I run this code from tomcat, which itself run in cygwin, the OS is Windows Server 2016.
What i found is the `exe` file is not run until I login Windows, pretty strange. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your stack trace  to understand your problem ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.